# Scale according Rotation in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

I'm trying to create a geometry nodes system that one side of my instance always start on the position 0 and always ends on the world position 1 (even if it is rotated). To make this happen, I'm using a transformation node and trying to make the instance scales according the rotation.
For this project, the rotation limits are between 0° and 45°.  I managed to get the scale to work when the object is at 0° and also when it's at 45°, the problem is the values in between, like 22,5°.
Any idea what node or function I could use to achieve this result?
Thanks in advance for any help!
[image: an example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a little bit of trig.

The length of the rod, (with length `L` at 0 degrees,) is `L/cos(theta)`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! This helped me a lot and I will definitely use it more in future studies with Blender.

Answer (score 6):

You can actually calculate the scaling based on a right triangle.

$b$ is at the beginning the one side with a scaling of $1$. If you change the angle, you would only have to calculate $c$, which is also your value for the scaling:

$c = \sqrt{b(tan^2(α) + b)}$

Translated into *Geometry Nodes* it should look like this:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Crikey.. you've dug up one of the most obscure [trig, identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) !  I never learned that one.. :D

Comment: @RobinBetts Ahem, yes, I am not very proud of it ;-) ...but it works! In the end, I'm just more the type for weird thoughts, and you are the math pro :D

Comment: Nope.. no way pro.  The only one i remember is SOHCAHTOA. Oh, and  sin squared + cos squared = 1.   The rest is trial and error :)

Comment: Thanks very much for the help!
I knew that the solution could be related to a calculation based on a triangle, but I had no idea how to solve it, especially in blender 
I will start studyng more about trigonometric functions to learn how to solve this kind of problem too. Thank you!

Comment: @ThiagoVieira You're welcome! But to be honest, even if the answer works perfectly: The solution of *RobinBetts* is a tad better, due to the lower number of nodes ;-)